# Suppose that R(s, t − 1) and R(s − 1, t) are both even numbers..

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Suppose that R(s, t − 1) and R(s − 1, t) are both even numbers. Prove that
R(s, t) ≤ R(s, t − 1) + R(s − 1, t) − 1.

I'm trying to learn proofs for graph theory and Ramsey theory but i'm strugging to formulate this result.. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of $R$ ?

Comment: Do you understand the usual proof of $R(s,t) \le R(s,t-1) + R(s-1,t)$? Start there.